# Creating onclick rows when displaying a database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a database which displays results of all employees that are stored in it.

It works and displays all the employees but I was wondering if its possible to make each
row click-able referring to a specific id.

I thought I would have to create a for each function that loops  through every row and make them onClick but i am still very very confused.

```
    Controller

$this->load->model('Employee_model');
$results = $this->Employee_model->search($offset,$sort_by,$sort_order);
$data['employees'] = $results['rows'];
$data['num_results'] = $results['num_rows'];

$this->load->view('employees', $data);


    Model
function search($sort_by, $sort_order)
{

//result query
$q = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('employees')
    ->order_by($sort_by,$sort_order)


      // if onclick row then display additional information


}

 view
<?php foreach($employees as $row): ?>
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->gender; ?> </td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: To give a definite answer, we need the code that passes the results to the view (or post the relevant code in the view file itself). Right now, I can only recommend that you add another controller that takes the id as the parameter and display the information.

Comment: you foreach with `$row`, but use `$employee` for the table cells?

Comment: `onclick` is a Javascript term, do you really need a Javascript click event, or do you just need a standard link (anchor) that goes to an employee details page?

Comment: it can be either to be honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like;
in view;

```
<?php foreach($employees as $row): ?>
<tr data-id="<?php echo $employee->id; ?>"> 
    <td><?php echo $employee->first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $employee->last_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $employee->gender; ?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("tr").click(function() {
    window.location = 'your-controller/the-id-view-function/'+$(this).data('id');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the onclick event is handled by Javascript in a HTML page. So basically what you need to do is:

In a php script retrieve the database info and, as you said, do a loop. Either store the HTML code into a variable or echo it, but keep in mind you have to output a whole correct HTML page (with `html`, `head` and `body` tags).

You can either insert the onclick event on the HTML you return from PHP or declare a click event from Jquery. The first is more simple so I'll give an example using this method

```
while(something){ //loop through all DB results
    $table_tr.="<tr onclick='do_something_when_tr_click(".$id_from_db.")'><td>$data_from_db</td></tr>";

}

echo "<html><head><script>(javascript functions go here)</script></head><body><table>$table_tr</table></body></html>";
```